# "Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure" error

Tags: maven, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, jmeter

Good day! I would like to ask about the error that I'm encountering in **Jenkins**:

- "Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure"

I'm trying to run a selenium script (with JMeter script inside) in Jenkins. I'm getting a BUILD SUCCESS in console output in Jenkins but it marks the job failed because of that error. Kindly see below the console output:

```
Running TestSuite
Start: 11/04/2016 5:19:29 PM
RawConfigFileScenario3 is created
11/04/2016 5:19:49 PM [PASSED] No Error encountered on the Jmeter Script
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 23.962 sec - in TestSuite

Results :

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 48.165 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-11-04T17:19:50+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/137M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I also tried to run the same script in Eclipse and I'm getting a SUCCESS result. Please see below the logs:

```
Running TestSuite
Start: 11/04/2016 4:26:26 PM
RawConfigFileScenario3 is created
11/04/2016 4:26:41 PM [PASSED] No Error encountered on the Jmeter Script
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 17.739 sec - in TestSuite

Results :

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 37.743 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-11-04T16:26:41+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/136M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I would like to ask for your guidance regarding this matter. Thank you in advance for the answers. :)

Comment: What did you set as goal in "Invoke top-level Maven targets"?

Comment: "Invoke top-level Maven targets" is a step in Jenkins job. So can you post a screenshot of your Jenkins build configuration?

Comment: Try running the command on the console of the Jenkins build slave and check the return code of the command.

Comment: Update on the issue. I was able to resolve it by changing the configured jdk in jenkins to jdk1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have encounter this problem. and i just change the sdk configuration from java8 to java7.

hope this can help you.